# Specify a number of ipengine instances to be launched within ipyparallel cluster

Tags: python, distributed-computing, ipython-parallel

Speaking of `ipyparallel`, is it possible to specify a number of `ipengines` to simultaneously launch on a slave machine, and if so - how do I do it?

For example, one can specify a number of engines to launch on localhost with `ipcluster start -n` command, i.e. `$ ipcluster start -n 4`, but `-n` flag does not work with `ipengine` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/process.html#using-the-ipcontroller-and-ipengine-commands) explicitly state that you need to "repeatedly" call `ipengine`:

> Next, start however many instances of the engine you want using
>   (repeatedly) the command:

```
$ ipengine
```

---

To start 4 engines from the "slave machine" use this at the command line:

```bash
for engine in {1..4}
do
  ipengine &
done
```

It's probably worth also reading [starting the controller and engines on different hosts](http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/process.html#starting-the-controller-and-engines-on-different-hosts).